# how to add event handler for Dom created in Desktop Notification?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Desktop Notification API on Chrome, I inserted a textbox into notification pop-up created with `window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(...`, and bind `keypress` event.

When the pop-up appears, I type some character but event handler for `keypress` doesn't work.
So, how to make it work?

Comment: Would you be willing to share some more of your code so we can help you improve your understanding instead of just giving you working code?